# Load HTML page stored in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I'd like to create a HTML app that stores another web page (HTML+CSS+JS in one file) in IndexedDB and can open it in the browser.

I know that I can do it using File system API: create temporary file, write page content from DB to this file and change browser location to this file. But I read that Filesystem API is supported only by Chrome so I'm wondering if there is another approach, supported by standards?

Comment: you can store all day, it's re-linking the external assets without http URLs that's a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your document as a string then you can use data URL scheme to load it in window:

```
window.open('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + 
    encodeURIComponent( // Escape for URL formatting
        '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
        '<html lang="en">'+
        '<head><title>Embedded Window</title></head>'+
        '<body><h1>42</h1></body>'+
        '</html>'
    )
);
```

Comment: i would prefer `open(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([strOfHTML], {type:"text/html"})))` over dataURLs, but you still have the problem of linked resources like imported spreadsheets.

Comment: @dandavis We've been told that "HTML+CSS+JS in one file" so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: whether that's "on us" is vague. i think we can all agree that writing out several local files from the one and then navigating to that file:/// will work well and wide, whereas dataURL and blobURLs have additional restrictions that could break the page; missing localStorage for example...

Comment: Depends on requirements. It could be easier to insert that chunk inside host document as a fragment. If it requires valid localStorage and contains relative resources.

Comment: good point. reminds me that you can also launder domains with document.write() or $.html()...

Comment: would this be the solution to this question or what should be done to complete such  objective https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029632/ublock-origin-filter-syntax-it-has-successfully-removes-elements-of-a-site-what